# Unable to Redraw NavGraph Fragments Using setGraph()

Tags: android, graph, navigation, navgraph

How can I force Navigation Components to redraw the fragments inside a navGraph from scratch?

I've tried using setGraph() with the same instance of the navGraph, but it only works the first time. The next time I call the same code with the same instance of the navGraph, it does nothing. Any suggestions on whats the best way to refresh the navGraph and redraw the fragments?

```
navGraph.setStartDestination(R.id.stories_nav_graph)
navController.setGraph(navGraph)
```

Answer (score 0):

**Reason:**

When setting the navigation graph using the Navigation component, if you pass the same instance of the navGraph that was already used to set the graph, the navController will not redraw the fragments in the graph from scratch.

**Solution:**

Inflating a new instance of the navGraph right before calling setStartDestination and setGraph ensures that all fragments in the graph are redrawn from scratch, which is the expected behavior in my case.

```
val navGraph = navController.navInflater.inflate(R.navigation.nav_graph)
navGraph.setStartDestination(R.id.stories_nav_graph)
navController.setGraph(navGraph)
```